# Java calling a synchronized function from while condition

Tags: java

Consider following code snippet.

```
public Class RunThread extends Thread{
    private boolean shouldContinueFlag;

    public synchronized boolean shouldContinue(){
        return shouldContinueFlag;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(shouldContinue()){
            //do  stuff;
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }
}

public Class AccessThread {
    // Somehow this class got RunThread Object and running in different thread context than RunThread. 
    public void AcessFunction(RunThread  runThrObj){
        if(runThrObj.shouldContinue()){
            //Do other stuff
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    }
}
```

Confusion is - How RunThread will behave while accessing synchronized method inside while condition. Will it acquire lock on class RunThread object followed by printing 'A' and then release the lock? or it will create a temporary variable to hold return value of shouldContinue() and then print 'A"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will acquire and release the lock for iteration of the while loop, which is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: Any detailed explanation why it is like that ?

Comment: That is the language spec! You call a synchronized method, you grab the monitor, the method exits, the monitor is released, period!

Answer (score 1):

The lock lasts during the execution of shouldContinue(), so it will lock, unlock, print A. Lock, unlock, print A, over and over.